# Firebase dynamic links not working after installing app from app store ios

Tags: react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links for my React Native project, but encountering issues on iOS devices.
the android is working as expected but the ios is like it forgets the dynamic links after installing my app from the app store. Please help me!
I have:

- set custom scheme in the info.plist
- set Associated Domains
- set [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"https://mydeeplink.page.link"; in AppDelegate.m